# Remove leading zeros from a number in a string

Tags: java, string, trim

I wanna trim this string.

"0000819780"

How i can get just the "819780" part.

I can do it with my way, just curious is there any "elegant" or "right" way to do this.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `819780` part?

Comment: What does your way return for "0000000"? Empty string or "0"?

Comment: Is the string input always a number?

Comment: My way is create two variable eg. a, b. a is for tracking the first char. b is for the next char. then i check if the b is not same with a, then i get the rest of variable. Thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this works:

```
try {
   int i = Integer.parseInt(yourString);
   System.out.println(i);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
   // the string is not a number
}
```

Comment: And then int to string if you need.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways you might remove leading zeros from your `String`; one approach, iterate the `String` from left to right stopping at the next to the last character (so you don't erase the final digit) stop if you encounter a non-zero and invoke `String.substring(int)` like

```
String str = "0000819780";
for (int i = 0, length = str.length() - 1; i < length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) != '0') {
        str = str.substring(i);
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Alternatively, parse the `String` like

```
int v = Integer.parseInt(str);
System.out.println(v);
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternative:

Using Apache Commons [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class:

```
StringUtils.stripStart(String str, String stripChars);
```

For your example:

```
StringUtils.stripStart("0000819780", "0");  //should return "819780"
```

Answer (score 5):

An elegant pure java way is just `"0000819780".replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")`

Comment: That would return an empty string for input "0000".

Answer (score 2):

If the input is always a number and you want to remove only the beginning zeroes, just parse it into an integer. If you want it in string format, parse it back.

```
String a = "0000819780";
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(a));
```

Check https://ideone.com/7NMxbE for a running code.

If it can have values other than numbers, you would need to catch `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Maybe use `Long`. Not all ten digit integers fit into `Integer`.

Comment: @Thilo, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(str.length() >= 1 && str.charAt(0) == '0')
   str = str.substring(1);
```

Comment: Sadly, you remember *incorrectly*. It only removes whitespace at the beginning and end of a `String`.

Comment: Alright, thanks for that. A simple while loop should do the trick then.

Answer (score 1):

Double abc = Double.parseDouble("00346632");

String xyz = String.format("%.0f", abc);